# What is the probability mass function of max(X1, X2)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let X1 and X2 be two independent random variables both having discrete uniform distribution over 1, 2,.., n for some positive integer n.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: Consider $P(\max(X_1, X_2)) \leq k$.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are independent the event $(max(X_1,X_2)\le k)=(X_1\le k)\cap (X_2\le k)$, which has a probability of $(\frac{k}{n})^2$.